# PyCharm Virtual Environment Concept - Understanding

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Was looking for this type of question, and didn't found one, If it does exist - I apologise, and feel free to delete this.

I'm currently working with PyCharm for a while, and while creating different sum-projects libraries under my main project:
[project libraries and sub-projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0vbv.png)
So far i did try for several time creating and activating different venv using:

```
python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment

source newproject/bin/activate
```

As far as I understand, there's no need to 'source /bin/activate/' any Virtual env.(?), is this something that is mandatory ? working with virtual environment in PyCharm ?
just to clarify - i'm currently installing different modules using the PyCharm Project interpreter.
[Project Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOM9z.png) 
- MacOS
- python3.7

Would love if someone could 'simplify' this concept.
Best.

Comment: you can configure the project interpreter under settings

Comment: 1. Pycharm can create a venv for you or you can connect an already existing (including manually created) venv to your project. 2. In pycharm's console itself, the project venv is used.